# Is there a way to mass input data validation in google sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a drop down menu with contents based on a another cell in the same row.  For example if A1 = 'yes' then the drop down in B2 gives you the options of 'yes' or 'no'.  I can do this I have the list data set up and to code works.  The problem is I need to do this 155 times in 4 different sheets.  Is there a faster way to do this than right clicking and editing the data validation rules for each cell.  Here's a link to the test sheet I'm working on :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rd_Ig_wpof9R_L0IiA1aZ9syO7BWxb6jvBhPqG8Jmm4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can set data validation rules with a script, [as documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationsrules). Here's a reference for [starting with Apps scripts](https://www.google.com/script/start/).

I wrote a function that does approximately what you described. It works with the range B3:B157 of the sheet '9th grade' in the current spreadsheet. For each of them, it sets the validation rule to be: a value in the same row, columns B and C of sheet 'List Data'. The line with

```
 ....... = listData.getRange(i+3, 2, 1, 2);
```

will need to be modified if the source range of validation is to be different. Here, the parameters are: starting row, starting column,  number of rows, number of columns. So, 2 columns starting with the second, in row numbered i+3.

```
function setRules() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var grade = ss.getSheetByName('9th Grade');
  var listData = ss.getSheetByName('List Data');
  var range = grade.getRange('B3:B157');
  var rules = range.getDataValidations();
  for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
    var sourceRange = listData.getRange(i+3, 2, 1, 2);
    rules[i][0] = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange).build();
  }
  range.setDataValidations(rules);
}
```

Comment: I keep getting a "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 8, file "Code")"  on line 8.  Any ideas as to why?

Comment: The message says that listData is null, instead of being a sheet pointer. It was supposed to be acquired on the line `var listData = ss.getSheetByName('List Data');` -- which raises the question of whether your spreadsheet has a sheet named "List Data".

Answer (score 0):

I land in this issue for a diferent reason: **"Just mass DataValidation copy (or update) in one column"**. Thanks, to user3717023 that bring me a light.
I hope that helps someone this simplification.

```
function setRules() { 
  //select spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var leads = ss.getSheetByName('Leads');

  //Select correct Datavalidation
  var rangeNewDataValidation = leads.getRange('M2:M2');
  var rule = rangeNewDataValidation.getDataValidations();

  //Copy (or Update) Datavalidation in a specific (13 or 'M') column
  var newRule = rule[0][0].copy();
  Logger.log(leads.getMaxRows())
  for( var i=3; i <= leads.getMaxRows(); i++){
    var range = leads.getRange(i, 13);
    range.setDataValidations([[newRule.build()]]);
  }

}
```